# Mongoose | populate on post middleware for "save"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Please consider the following `parentSchema` and `childSchema`:

```
const parentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    children: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Child" }],
});

const childSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    parent: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Parent" },
});
```

How do I access the name of the parent within a post middleware of the childSchema?
I am trying the code below but `parent` is assigned the ObjectId instead of the actual parent model.

```
childSchema.post("save", async function (child) {
    const parent = child.populate("parent").parent;
});
```

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: use await before the populate, and I know what is the `.parent` at the end of query

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi that makes no difference. Btw, `child` is a model, not a query.

Comment: for getting additional information that inserted into other collection (parent collection) need to a query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to populate something after the initial fetch you need to call `execPopulate` -- e.g.:

```ts
childSchema.post("save", async function (child) {
    try {
        if (!child.populated('parent')) {
            await child.populate('parent').execPopulate();
        }
        const parent = child.populate("parent").parent;
    } catch (err) {}
});
```

Comment: Note that this isn't correct anymore in mongoose 6 and later -- populate behavior changed

Answer (score 0):

I just found out about `this.model("Model")` so I'm sharing another solution. Not sure how it compares with the accepted one, though:

```
childSchema.post("save", async function (child) {
    try {
        const parent = await this.model("Parent").findOne({ _id: child.parent });
        parent.children.push(child._id);
        parent.save();
    } catch (error) {}

});
```